# Constant definition in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `initializers config` in my rails application under `config/initializers/my_config.rb`.

What is the difference between:

**A:**

```
module MyModule
  Config = "path/to/config.yml"
end
```

and:

**B:**

```
MyModule::Config = "path/to/config.yml"
```

Let's suppose we do some requests, change its implementation, and hit the application again. If I defined my constant the **B** way, I get an error:

```
uninitialized constant MyModule::Config
```

It will be resolved only when I restart my rails server. But when I do the **A** way, it still recognized the constant when I updated my code.

What is the importance of using the **A** syntax in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of this seems to have to do with rails [hot code reloading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html), which has a bunch of caveats. If you aren't using hot code reloading, *A* and *B* are more equivalent, as long as `MyModule` has been defined first.

However, when code is reloaded, (particularly the file that defines `MyModule`), it might end up overwriting the existing module, and not running the *B* line.

The main difference though,  is that *A* doesn't rely on how the order of other code in the project is loaded/run, but *B* must be run *after* certain code.

Comment: That [link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) goes into more detail about how reloading works in rails, and is more specific than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The differences is that code A raises a syntax error, while code B is grammatical. Code B will raise a name error for `MyModule` unless it is previously defined, though.